# file_get_contents returns false while trying to save an image from a cdn URL

Tags: php, file-get-contents

can I use this URL for `file_get_contents`? Or is this my issue?

```
URL of the image -> //cdn.abc.de/images/100/0/8/0/1/5/8/080158F1.jpg?output-format=progressive-jpeg&resize=384px:511px

$contents= file_get_contents($arr_data_product->image); //return false
```

Thank you.

I get the URL from a website.

```
<img width="384" height="511" id="productImage" src="//cdn.abc.de/images/100/0/8/0/1/5/8/080158F1.jpg?output-format=progressive-jpeg&amp;resize=384px:511px">
```

Comment: The url given is not opening in browser... Please check url ??

Comment: I crawl it from a website. The URL of the image is from an image tag. I edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

Doesn't work:

```
//cdn.abc.de/images/100/0/8/0/1/5/8/080158F1.jpg?output-format=progressive-jpeg&resize=384px:511px
```

Works:

```
http://cdn.abc.de/images/100/0/8/0/1/5/8/080158F1.jpg?output-format=progressive-jpeg&resize=384px:511px
```

Answer (score 0):

When you crawl from some page its always better to curl and check for http_code in header as the given url might not exist as per in your case. Only do file_get_content in case you get the crawled url exist. By this way you can handle error